# flutter countdown timer running until it runs out

Tags: flutter, timer, background, lifecycle

I'm working to do a simple countdown and it works great

but the problem is that when I switch to another page, the countdown counter does not continue from where it left off.

eg I initialize the counter: 10 , 9, 8 ...

the page changes and the counter starts again at 10

here is my code

```
My package: import 'package:circular_countdown_timer/circular_countdown_timer.dart';

class _CircularTimerState extends State<CircularTimer> {
  final CountDownController controller = CountDownController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
  }

  void miningCounter() {
    controller.start();
    final user = context.read<FirebaseAuthMethods>().user;

    dbRef.child(user.uid).child('miningEndTime').set(endTime);
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Circular Timer'),
        backgroundColor: primaryMaterialColor,
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          // Countdown Start Button
          CustomMiningButton(
            icon: Icons.start,
            onTap: miningCounter,
          ),

          CircularCountDownTimer(
            duration: 10,
            initialDuration: 0,
            controller: controller,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
            autoStart: false,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to share where in your code your switching to another page?

Comment: i am changing page in bottom navigation i mean from another page

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember what was the last number. You can use the [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) package:

Create a class:

```
class SharedPref {
  static late final SharedPreferences prefs;

  static initialize() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  SharedPref._();
}
```

Call the initialize method in your main function:

```
void main() async {
   await SharedPref.initialize();
   runApp(...);
}
```

Then before you open the next page you save the value:

```
SharedPref.prefs.setInt("remaining", _remaining);
```

Have a variable that holds this number:

```
 final CountDownController controller = CountDownController();
 late int _remaining;
 bool _loading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
    _setRemaining();
  }

  _setRemaining() async {
    _remaining = await SharedPref.prefs.getInt("remaining");

    setState(() { _loading = false; });
  }


...

body: _loading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          // Countdown Start Button
          CustomMiningButton(
            icon: Icons.start,
            onTap: miningCounter,
          ),

          CircularCountDownTimer(
            duration: 10,
            initialDuration: _remaining,
            controller: controller,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
            autoStart: false,
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: i got this error when i followed the steps in order` LateError (LateInitializationError: Field '_remaining@50123027' has not been initialized.) `

Comment: Because you try to use the `_remaining` variable before you set a value for it. If it runs first, then you won't get any data from shared preferences. You can try to add this: `if (_remaining == null) { _remaining = 10; }` after `... await SharedPref.prefs...`

Comment: can you post a compiled version of the code for me?

Answer (score 0):

I think passing key to the page would work

Here is YouTube vedio for your case :-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sMD4Qxn9q_E

Comment: page storage keys did not work