# How to save the value of counter each time I change it in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I have created a counter app in flutter. I pressed the increment button for 10 times. It was showing the counter value was 10 on the screen. But whenever i exit the app and reopen it shows the counter value is 0. Why is this happening? I want to save the counter value each time I change it. Can somebody solve my problem???

Comment: Can you include [/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), You can save the on [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Comment: I answered this question yesterday... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72938792/flutter-countdown-timer-running-until-it-runs-out/72938997#72938997

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the on `shared_preferences`

```dart
class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ParentWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ParentWidget> createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  bool _isMuted = false;

  int counter = 0;

  SharedPreferences? preferences;

  Future<void> initStorage() async {
    preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // init 1st time 0
    int? savedData = preferences?.getInt("counter");
    if (savedData == null) {
      await preferences!.setInt("counter", counter);
    } else {
      counter = savedData;
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initStorage();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          preferences?.setInt("counter", counter += 1);
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text("${preferences?.getInt("counter")}"),
```

More about [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences). Also you can check Hive and others local data storage.